# In app calling without redirecting to Phone activity

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to know if there is any method to make a phone call in Android without redirecting the uri to Phone Activity. To make a phone call,

```
String uri2 = "tel:678-547-9181";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri2));
startActivity(intent);
```

This was the code i was using earlier. But this redirects to phone activity and makes a call. But i dont want to reveal the phone number to the user. Is there any way that i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible from an SDK application, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Mark. This means that you have to venture into Android NDK coding if you want to achieve this.

Comment: @Rahul Varma: No, this means that you have to roll your own firmware "if you want to achieve this".