# How to make GSM calls via code

Tags: android

I have a requirement where I would want to initiate and manage GSM calls (Like the ones we make via Phone)

I will be connecting to a GSM Module/DTMF Module (context: robotics) via this method and would be sending instructions via DTMF tones.

I don't want to open up the phone dialer via an `Intent` with `tel:` data, would rather want to manage the telephony myself.

First thought that the system might not allow a third-party app, without a signature matching system's signature, to do telephony stuff, but then I wondered how some of the apps available in the market are doing it. (I'll attach links as soon as I find suitable ones)

**EDIT:** The apps that I had seen, were launchers and call manager apps, and once installed, had replaced my default phone apps (and thus were making calls instead of the default phone app doing it)

**EDIT:** I have found this question asking something similar, and also has an answer: [Android Dialer application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5029183/243709). I'll try this out and post back if I get any success.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I wondered how some of the apps available in the market are doing it" -- I am not aware of any apps on the Play Store that "initiate and manage GSM calls" or are "sending instructions via DTMF tones".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I had seen a few apps, which were launchers, and had replaced my default phone application. (I am updating the question)

Comment: "and thus were making calls instead of the default phone app doing it" -- that is accomplished via `ACTION_CALL` `Intents`, `startActivity()`, and the `CALL_PHONE` permission, as noted in the answer on your 2nd edit.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try that out and will post back here.

Comment: I tried those codes out, but they all are opening the default phone dialer, which I would not want. Seems like there are certain limitations which will not let me do so. I came around one of your answers which clearly says that its not possible via current SDK to make calls without that intent action: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5605706/243709